# Custom rule for user selections in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, rule

I am using sitecore 8.1 and we have a custom domain let's say it "**website**" we have registration form through which users create their account/profile with custom properties like first name, area , age and gender etc.
Now we need to select a group of users let's say "**male users from xyz city and above 18 etc...**". I have basic understanding that i would be using a sitecore's **rule** field.
I have created a template with field as rule which have empty field now where to define rule ? I have looked into "" for pre-defined rule but did not found any relevant option and i guess that we have to go for custom rule so i created a new "Rules Context Folder" it have empty rule folder wothout any insert option **:)**

Guys any guide or link to relevant article etc....

Comment: Have you looked at this yet? https://jeffdarchuk.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/lets-use-that-rules-engine/

Comment: This setup still applies in sitecore 8.

Comment: Are these values be stored in the index?